# Especificar categoria en un Array en PHP

Tags: php

Tengo un array  pero necesito que este especifique por categoría, ejemplo **usuario y adicional** , como se muestra abajo...

**Este es mi código:**

```
  $datos = array(  
        
        "email" =>$email,
        "name" => $name,
    
    
        "ship" =>$ship,
        "phone" => $phone,
    );
```

---

**De esta manera :**

```
"usuario": {
      "email"  => "Prueba",
      "name" => "Prueba",
    },
  "adicional": { 
     "ship" => "2020-10-01"    ,
      "phone" => "11111111",
  },
```

¿Cómo podría imprimir los datos clasificados de esa manera?

---

¿Sería correcto de esta manera ?

```
  $datos = array(  
        "usuario: {"
        "email" =>$email,
        "name" => $name,
       "}",
    
      "adicional: {"
        "ship" =>$ship,
        "phone" => $phone,
       "}",
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que lo mas adecuado sería o crear 2 arrays diferentes, uno para datos personales y otro para datos adicionales o puedes crear un array de este modo.

```
$datos = array( 
    
    'Usuario' => array(
        'email' => "email",
        'name'  => "name"
    ),
    
    'Adicional' => array(
        'ship' => "ship",
        'phone'  => "phone"
    )
);
```

Para imprimir los datos tan solo debes de recorrer tu array multidimensional de este modo usando un foreach:

```
foreach($productos as $producto => $detalles)
{
    echo "<h1> $producto </h1>";
 
    foreach($detalles as $indice => $valor)
    {
        echo "<p> $indice:$valor </p>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$datos = (object)[
"usuario" => (object)[
        "email" =>$email,
         "name" => $name], 
"adicional" => (object) [
        "ship" =>$ship,
        "phone" => $phone] 
 ] ;
```

Recuerdo en la versión 5.4 se definía así espero te sirva